# How to get selected item information from a DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to create a combobox in a datagrid. So far I have the two versions of this combobox and neither one works as desired.

The following code can save changes in the datagrid but cannot load the value (referred to as V1 later)

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Direction" Width="*">
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Type"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding dt}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>

<DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.paramDirection}"/>
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding dt}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

The following code can load the value but cannot save it (referred to as V2 later)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnHeader">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding dt.Name}" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbbx" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.paramDirection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding dt}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

I access the value in the combobox via an event to command function

> currentCellValue = (((ComboBox)e.EditingElement).SelectedItem);

This line works fine on V1 but not V2. So I want to know if there is a way to get 'SelectedItem' information out of a DataGridTemplateColumn (if so how and if not what are the alternatives).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DisplayMemberPath`, `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValueBinding` properties of the column itself:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Direction" Width="*" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Type" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding dt}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.paramDirection}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.paramDirection}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Hi mm8, I tried out your implementation (and various permutations of the same logic) but it had the same result as V1, where I can save the value but cannot retrieve it. 'dt' is the member that stores the value I am trying to display on startup and paramDirection is the list of valid options for the ComboBox (if that helps)

Comment: @Kid-Seven-7: What's the type of dt and where is the dt property defined? What's the ItemsSource of your  DataGrid?

Comment: Oh, so it turns out that my main issue was the fact the I had implemented my INotifyPropertyChanged in my Model instead of my ViewModel. After refactoring the code to properly implement mvvm the greater issues were resolved :$. Thank you for the assistance though, sorry about that

Comment: @Kid-Seven-7: My answer is still valid. You should set the properties of the column itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Dir" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type Type="pDIR:ParameterDirection"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Setting my options as a staticResource and binding to Direction

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="*" Header="Direction" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Direction}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Dir}}"/>
```

ultimatly worked, it added overhead but...